# Using "en" and "au" before a country

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

I see that sometimes “en” and “au” are used before a country. Can I always use “en” or there are some situations where I should use “au”?

Answer (score 6):

You can’t always use “*en*”. **When you need to** use “*à*” + country, you’ll need to use “*au*” if the country’s name is singular masculine and begins with a consonant sound, “*en*” when it is singular feminine or singular masculine and begin with a vowel sound, and “aux” when it is plural.

> Le Danemark, l’Afghanistan, la Belgique, les États-Unis

become

> Au Danemark, en Afghanistan, en Belgique, aux États-Unis.